# How do I obtain selected rows in a DataGridView from different pages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows forms DataGridView, where I have data and a checkbox for each row.

I will select check box for a particular row and all the selected rows will be populated in another page.

```
if (grdEmp.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedEmpIDs= from DataGridViewRow coll in grdEmp.Rows
                                     where Convert.ToBoolean(coll.Cells["Select"].Value) == true
                                     select coll;
            if (selectedEmpIDs.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedEmpIDs)
                {
                    selectedEmp+= row.Cells["EmpId"].Value + ",";
                }
            }
        }
```

This works good only for one page.

When I navigate to another page, and click the selected rows, the previous one goes off.

How do I resolve it.

Thanks
cmrhema

Note :Sorry for the confusion, When I meant it works good for a page, I meant paging.

I think I need to add more inputs,

There are 10 pages in the gridview.

I select the first record from each page of the gridview, one after another by clicking next page( Page next button).

But only the record that was selected the last is getting displayed and others and ignored off.

What could be the prblm

Comment: you will have to retain the selected ids like in a hidden field and then check it again via jquery

Comment: @V4Vendetta: JQuery in Winforms? And even in WebForms if you are navigating between pages How can we access hidden fields from previous page using JQuery?

Comment: @Anuraj: sorry my mistake ... i thought he was referring to paging

Comment: How are you providing paging? Show some more of your code. One possibility - are the ids actually unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List or Dictionary or any other collection type globally, using Program.cs or using a static class. And store the selected rows into the list before you leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a comma delimited string string for your list of ids you can instead use a List.

Your code will then become something like this:

```
if (grdEmp.Rows.Count > 0)         
{             
    var selectedEmpIDs= from DataGridViewRow coll in grdEmp.Rows                                      
    where Convert.ToBoolean(coll.Cells["Select"].Value) == true                                      s
    select coll;             

    if (selectedEmpIDs.Count() > 0)             
    {                 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedEmpIDs) 
        {
            if (!listOfIds.Contains((int)row.Cells["EmpId"].Value))
            {
                listOfIds.Add(((int)row.Cells["EmpId"].Value));
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

You will need methods to remove items from this list so adding event handlers for the checkbox selected event will probably work better.

The List object itself can simple live as a class level object of the form that containst your DataGridView.

This gets a little bit more complicated if you are managing your paging across forms, but the same principles of maintaining a list of selected ids applies.